# CPU is over utilised and unable to find out the root cause

Tags: google-compute-engine

We have upgraded to 6vCPUs 7.5GB and sliver plan as we are getting continues issues don't how to resolve those so we have  upgraded to the above plans, after upgrading to sliver plan in how much time can we raise a case, presently when we try to raise a case it's taking us to role based support where we are unable to raise ticket.

At regularly our CPU is over utilised and unable to find the root cause for it. Please help us to resolve this issues

We are using PHP application with CMS Drupal 8 and maintaining around 5 love sites in it.

Comment: What do you mean by over utilized, load average or busy %?  Please provide the name and version of your PHP version, web server, database server, and operating system (which Linux distro).

Answer (score 0):

Normally when you upgrade to Silver, Gold or Platinum support package, you can use the [Google Cloud Support Center](https://support.google.com/googlecloud/answer/1041916?hl=en) to create and manage support cases.

1. Go to the support center.
2. Find the product you need help with in the product list.
3. Click New Case, complete the form, and click Submit.

If you are still facing an issue creating a case you can as well open a private issue on the issue tracker and include all of the info we will need to investigate (project number, cluster IDs, etc).

Your issue is most probably about upgrading the machine type to allocate more resources such as CPU and memory.